# Sentry/Raven on an Electron React app - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, sentry

relative newbie here...
Trying to get Sentry to take-in my electron (react) app.

Docs say to npm install the raven-js module.
Then run a:
    `Raven.config(https://${publicSentryKey}@sentry.io/projectNumber).install();`

I've tried changing this to a method, calling it in, with console logs either side so i know it's firing off.

But i keep getting the same errors in the dev-tools (`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`).

NOTE
docs say to put a CDN in the HTML. There is a diff one for npm than common-js. I've tried both. no joy.

To add further confusion - this has connected successfully twice today, but there was a delay on it of about 8 minutes. Meaning i was trying to fix it when it was connected.

What am i doing wrong?

[image: Documentation Instructions]
[image: dev tools fail]

Comment: Not sure precisely what your issue is but I can confirm that `raven-js` package with `Raven.config(...).install()` has worked for me in Electron (in a `BrowserWindow` renderer process). No need for a separate script tag. I also used the `raven` node package in a similar way for the main process.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. I installed with npm as you did, and then added this to my js file:

```
import Raven from 'raven-js';
Raven.config('https://xxx@sentry.io/xxx').install();
```

using react, webpack etc from https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this.

`<script src="https://cdn.ravenjs.com/3.26.2/raven.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/integrations/react/